# Como convertir varias filas de una columna en una lista dentro de un dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Sucede que tengo 2 columnas que se interrelacionan: la primera son nombres y la segunda son conteos de entradas de esa persona en un gimnasio a la semana.

en la primer columna los nombres se repiten cuantas veces haya entrada en la segunda variable, así:

```
     c1  nom  entr       
0    0   E    1  
1    1   A    2  
2    2   B    5  
3    3   A    3  
4    4   C    6
```

existen repeticiones entre nombres con muchos valores en las entradas al gimnasio que se verían de esta forma:

```
     nom   entr
28   A    6
1    A    2
30   A    1
3    A    3
23   A    1
5    A    7
6    A    9
26   A    8
33   B    4
34   B    6
14   B    9
36   B    8
9    B    3
7    B    1
2    B    5
10   C    7
37   C    9
4    C    6
```

En  este caso  en vez de ver cada letra repitiéndose me gustaría ver solo 1 letra y las entradas al lado de esta, algo como esto:

supongamos que yo quiero ver la media de las entradas por nombre sería algo así

```
        entr
nom          
A    4.625000
B    5.142857
C    5.400000
D    3.833333
E    4.785714
```

esto mismo es lo que me gustaría ver pero con cada entrada, más o menos así pero con los valores reales

```
              entr
nom          
A    1:2:3:5:7:8:10
B         1:2:4:7:8
C             1:6:9
D    1:2:3:5:7:8:10
E    1:2:3:5:7:8:10
```

¿cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` para agrupar por nombre y luego simplemente usar `apply` sobre la columna `entr`:

> ```
> >>> import numpy as np
> >>> df2 = df.groupby("nom")['entr'].apply(np.array)
> >>> df2
>
> nom
> A    [6, 2, 1, 3, 1, 7, 9, 8]
> B       [4, 6, 9, 8, 3, 1, 5]
> C                   [7, 9, 6]
> Name: entr, dtype: object
> ```

Esto genera una Serie, pero si quieres un DataFrame basta con usar el método `to_frame` por ejemplo:

> ```
> >>> df2 = df.groupby("nom")['entr'].apply(np.array).to_frame()
> >>> df2
>
>                          entr
> nom                          
> A    [6, 2, 1, 3, 1, 7, 9, 8]
> B       [4, 6, 9, 8, 3, 1, 5]
> C                   [7, 9, 6]
> ```

Si quieres una lista Python, basta con usar:

```
df.groupby("nom")['entr'].apply(list).to_frame()
```

Ten en cuanta que ahora tu columna `entr` es de tipo `object` y esto ocasiona que el potencial de Pandas en cuanto a realizar operaciones vectorizadas de forma eficiente se vea muy mermado.

---

Solo por curiosidad, para obtener una salida como la que muestras puedes convertir las `entr` en una cadena de texto, aunque lógicamente desde el punto de vista de operar con los datos es una pésima idea:

> ```
> >>> df2 = df.groupby("nom")['entr'].apply(lambda arr: ":".join(map(str, arr)).to_frame()
> >>> df2
>                 entr
> nom                 
> A    6:2:1:3:1:7:9:8
> B      4:6:9:8:3:1:5
> C              7:9:6
> ```